# Find area of irregular 6 sided polygon (only by sdies)

Tags: geometry, area, polygons

I have to find area of 6 sided irregular polygon, and I have no angle here. Is  there a trick to find the area with this image information?
[image]

I got stuck on this problem. There is some online calculator for this reason but they need to out information as triangles.( But I do not know $AC,CE ,...$

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It's impossible without knowing the angles or the diagonals. You could find the angles with a goniometer on your picture.

Comment: Just imagine to build a model of that figure with six hinged bars. It's obvious your model can be deformed and its area changed.

Comment: all information which I have are the length of 6 sides

Comment: There is no unique solution. Think of a simpler example, a quadrilateral with all sides equal to 1. Then you can get a square, if the angles are $90^\circ$, but you can get a rhombus. The area of the rhombus is dependent on the smallest (or largest) angle.

Comment: @user2661923 I'd suggest you to draw that figure with GeoGebra: that'll be better than any theoretical explanation.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Good idea.  After re-considering, I deleted all of my previous comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does specifying the lengths of the sides of a polygon completely fix its shape (area and angles)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557564/does-specifying-the-lengths-of-the-sides-of-a-polygon-completely-fix-its-shape)

Answer (score 1):

For full *triangulation* we need $2n-3$ dimensions in a plane. ( $n$ is number of vertices or joints or nodes). Less than this number we have a mechanism with the vertices as hinges.

When $n=6$ we need 9, so three more dimensions (side lengths and/or angles) are needed without which a construction is impossible.

[Static indeterminacy in Trusses](http://ecoursesonline.iasri.res.in/mod/page/view.php?id=125340)

$$ m=2 j-3 $$

This relation determines static indeterminacy in pin jointed trusses. Less than this $j$ the truss is statically indeterminate as in the given case of a mechanism ($ 2j-3=9$). More than this it is redundant, and is said to define *the degree of freedom.*

Unless the degree of freedom is zero area cannot be found.

Comment: Very interesting answer.  Can you recommend a source that discusses that full triangulation requires $(2n-3)$ dimensions in the plane?

Comment: It is derived easily in triangulated trusses. Each extra joint $j$ or vertex gives two extra members. So it is of the form $2j +k$ where $k$ is found from special case of a triangle.